# Сравнение двух массивов с неполным совпадением

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
import itertools

_ = None  # 0 or 1
A = [
    [1, _, 1, _],
    [0, 1, _, 0],
    [_, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

B = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

P = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for p in itertools.permutations(P):
    if [[B[p[i]][p[j]] for j in P] for i in P] == A:  # ???
        print(p)
        break
```

Как остановить цикл при нахождении неполного совпадения?

Comment: есть 2 массива. А перестановки вам зачем?

Answer (score 2):

> Сравнение двух массивов с неполным совпадением

```
def compareWithNones(A, B):
    for i, row in enumerate(A):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
            b_cell = B[i][j]
            if cell is not None and b_cell is not None and cell != b_cell:
                return False
    return True


_ = None  # 0 or 1
A = [
    [1, _, 1, _],
    [0, 1, _, 0],
    [_, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

B = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

C = [
    [_, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, _, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, _, 0]
]


print(compareWithNones(A, B)) # False
print(compareWithNones(A, C)) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну я вам сравнивалку написал, только ничего всё-равно не находится. Мне кажется, там как-то по-другому надо перебирать, но как - не соображу:

```
def my_compare(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            a = A[i][j]
            if not a == _ and not a == B[i][j]:
                return False
    return True

P = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for p in itertools.permutations(P):
    if my_compare(A, [[B[p[i]][p[j]] for j in P] for i in P]):
        print(p)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться генераторами и встроенными функциями

```
def compareWithNones(A, B):
     return all(
          all(cell1 is None 
           or cell2 is None 
           or not (cell1-cell2) 
          for cell1, cell2 in zip(row1, row2)
         ) 
      for row1,row2 in zip(A,B))

print(compareWithNones(A, B)) # False
print(compareWithNones(A, C)) # True
```